# Location from Network Provider Android

Tags: android, location, android-gps

We are trying to get the location without using Location Manager or Google location protocols. We are trying to get the location directly from Network provider even if the Internet is off. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: share your code sinppet...

Comment: Hi Shivam, we are just in start of the implementation. Need best way to approach or some code snippet if available. Will be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used service for it which doesn't need internet.

```
public class LocationSS extends Service{
private static final String TAG=
"BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";

private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;

private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 5000;

private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 5f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener

{

Location mLastLocation;

public LocationListener(String provider)

    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocaenter code heretion = new Location(provienter code hereder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);

        String Loca="Log : "+ String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + ", Lat :"+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        SharedPreferences xxx = LocationSS.this.getSharedPreferences("lo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = xxx.edit();
        editor.putString("loco", Loca);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(LocationSS.this,Loca,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            } }} }

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is solution to get location

> http://ip-api.com/json/

this is the url and get your location details like lat,lon,city country and many other data

Comment: I want to get the location without internet conectivity

Comment: let me find solution